# How to align equations using curly brackets

Tags: amsmath, systeme

How can I align my equation like this

[image]

I can't get the second column. I have the first down.

```
    \begin{equation}\label{2.2}
  \systeme*{
  x_1^{'} = x_2,
  x_2^{'} = \frac{3}{t}x_2-x_1
  }
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `dcases`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{sensible-label}
\begin{dcases}
x_1'=x_2, & x_1(0)=10 \\
x_2'=\frac{3}{t}x_2-x_1, & x_2(0)={?}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note `{?}` or the spacing would be wrong. Also `^{'}` is wrong and should simply be `'`.

[image: text]

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to load only `mathtools`?

Comment: @Zarko Yes, but I prefer to load both for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative which places the comma in the centre (closer to the original picture) then you could use an align environment and fine tune some of the column spacing using `@{<some_spacing>}`, as in

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l@{\,}ll}
\dot{x}_1 = x_2 & \multirow{2}{*}{,} & x_1(0) = 10 \\
\dot{x}_2 = 0.02 x_1 + 1 & & x_2(0) = {?}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the better way to do this is as described by egreg and use `cases`.